# Update variables within makefile label

Tags: linux, makefile

I have C++ static libraries and executable that uses them, each one is in a seperate folder. Each such project can be built in Debug or Release configuration, when the files hierarchy is like the following:
Static_Lib1\Debug\staticlib1.a
Static_Lib1\Release\staticlib1.a
//same for all other static libraries
Executable\Debug\executable
Executable\Release\executable

All Debug and Release folders contain makefiles.
I'm trying to write an external makefile to call each one of the internal projects, using the selected configuration - debug or release.
So, I tried something like:

```
CFG= #empty declaration  
PROJECTS=Static_Lib1 Static_Lib2 ... Executable
all:  
  release #default config is release  

release:  
  CFG = Release  
  make build-all  

debug:  
  CFG = Debug  
  make build-all  

build-all:  
  make clean  
  $(foreach projectName, $(PROJECTS), cd $(projectName)/$(CFG) && make all;)
```

But I get this output when trying, for example, to run `make debug`:

```
CFG = Debug  
make: CFG: Command not found  
make: *** [debug] Error 127
```

How can I fix this?
My OS is SLED 11x64.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
...

release:  
  make CFG=Release build-all  

debug:  
  make CFG=Debug build-all  

...
```

Comment: Thats pointless. All that does is recall the makefile. You might as well get rid of both the release and debug targets and call `make CFG=WHATEVER build-all` directly